# How to verify SOAP signature w/ Delphi 2009?

Tags: delphi, soap, delphi-2009, digital-signature

I'm using the Clever Internet Suite in D2009 to sign a SOAP message and need a way to verify the signed document locally.  The server keeps bouncing the SOAP message with the error "Hash values do not match".

I have to manipulate the document slightly before submitting but not the signed section so I need to find out if this manipulation is causing the error.  I can also obtain the document received by the server and want to verify that copy to see if something is changing in transmission.

Is there a way using the Clever Suite?  Or maybe the Crypto.api?  Even a standalone app that I can feed the document and public key to would be fine.

Thank you for any information you can provide.

Comment: Not having luck with Clever we have been evaluating the Secure XML product from Eldos which has a demo project for signing and verifying.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to manipulate the document slightly before submitting but not the signed section so I need to find out if this manipulation is causing the error.

You can test for that by *not* manipulating it and testing if the error is still caused. If not, compare the two XML documents if there are only changes in the parts you think there are.

Also your question is about a year soon. Could you please update it with the information how you handling this now, what your workaround was etc?